# Python 3 cause Ctrl-C to exit input only, not program

Tags: python-3.x, user-input, exit, readline

After searching SO it appears most posts regarding `Ctrl^C` are about exiting the *program*, and I would like to just abort the `input( ... )` statement but not the program itself.  Here is the key code from the application:

```
import readline

def do_something() # ... see method call below
    command_str = readline_input(self.shell_prompt(), default_prompt)
    command_str = command_str.strip()
    

def readline_input(prompt, prefill=""):
    readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(prefill))
    try:
        return input(prompt)
    finally:
        readline.set_startup_hook()
```

How do I bind `Ctrl^C` to just exit that `input( .. )` prompt (as if I had entered nothing) vs. exiting the program?

Comment: you can use the signal module(signal.SIGINT): https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#module-signal

Answer (score 0):

IDK if this is what you are asking for but with the try function you have you can use

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```